# Android cannot find the method "implementation()"

Tags: android, gradle

So I am implementing some dependencies in the Gradle file and when I try to sync it, I get

```
Build file '/home/qwirrr/AndroidStudioProjects/ClockIn/build.gradle' line: 9

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ClockIn'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

The Gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried to change `implementation` to `compile` and even changing the Gradle version in the classpath line, with no success.

How do I fix this?

Note: I am using Pop_OS! 20.04 LTS if that matters

Comment: You are adding dependencies to the root build gradle, add them to your app's build.gradle

Comment: The `implementation` configuration is [added by the Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management). So you should add `plugins { id 'java' }` to the top of your build.gradle. In a `buildscript` block, you can only use `classpath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependencies should go into the `build.gradle` of your module/app not in the `build.gradle` of your project:

The `build.gradle` of your app should looks something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    ...
}

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    //all your dependencies goes here
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

The only thing that should go into the `build.gradle` of your project is the classpath.